# Passing Multiple Values Through Pipe While Making Dependent HTTP Requests without Using Closures

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Is there way to avoid storing a result using closures from an initial HTTP request for use in a second HTTP request, as well as, in the subscribe block?  The second request depends on the first so I can't use `combineLatest`, etc.

```js
let acceptedOrgAgreement = false;

// Initial HTTP request
this.organizationResource
  .getOrganizationById(organizationId)
  .pipe(
    // Initial HTTP response
    map((organization: Organization) => !!organization.acceptedAgreementDate),
    exhaustMap((hasSignedOrgAgreement: boolean) => {

      // Would rather not have to temporarily store this in outer function scope
      acceptedOrgAgreement = hasSignedOrgAgreement;

      // Second HTTP request that relies on the initial request
      return this.siteResource.updateSite(payload, hasSignedOrgAgreement);
    }),
    // Pass first and second HTTP responses to subscribe as tuple
    map((response: any) => [response, acceptedOrgAgreement])
  )
  .subscribe(([response, hasSignedOrgAgreement]: [any, boolean]) => {
    // Do some work using both responses
  });
```

Comment: `return thing(input).pipe(map((value) => [input, value]))`?

Comment: huh, yep that would do it.  For some reason I think about only a singular pipe, and didn't consider adding a pipe within the exhaustMap...

Answer (score 0):

what about return a `forkJoin` ?

```
this.organizationResource
  .getOrganizationById(organizationId)
  .pipe(
    map((organization: Organization) => !!organization.acceptedAgreementDate),
    exhaustMap((hasSignedOrgAgreement: boolean) => {
      return forkJoin([this.siteResource.updateSite(payload, hasSignedOrgAgreement), of(hasSignedOrgAgreement)]);
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(([response, hasSignedOrgAgreement]: [any, boolean]) => {
  });
```